# PYQT QPushButton Object to QML AND Back

Tags: python-3.x, qml, pyqt5

I am trying to use PyQt5 and QML for transferring images from USB camera (python) -> transform to numpyarray (or any other python dataType)
and Pass the image to QML object for streaming.

As it is not possible to pass an Image (through signals or property)
I will try to create some VideoOutput type on QML and pass it to python (by ref or something ) to shuv images inside it...

For start, I would like to create QButton on qml side, and reinterpret it as QPushButton on Python side (PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton)...

Pseudo Code :

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import (pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal, Q_CLASSINFO,
QCoreApplication, QDate, QObject, QTime, QUrl)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtQml import (qmlAttachedPropertiesObject, qmlRegisterType,
QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine, QQmlListProperty)

QML = b'''
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
Window{
height:300; width:200
Button
{
    id:b1
    objectName: "butbut"
}
```

main.py:

```
# create qml Engine and load QML into it
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QML)
pushbuttonFromQml = #somehow get the Button instance (referance) from QML through engine.
```

I'll appreciate ANY help...

Comment: Button in QML is not a QPushButton, it is not even a widget, on the other hand it is considered bad practice to try to move the objects of QML to python / C++, on the contrary you must do the opposite, why do you want to get the button on the side of python?

Comment: i am trying to stream data to the qml object from a python USB camera class... consider i have a real time stream of np.ndarray 2D arrays i want to stream to the qml object... what is the best approach in your opinion?